# Tensorflow: Multi-GPU single input queue

Tags: tensorflow

In [tensorflow's cifar10 multi-GPU example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10), it seems (correct me if I am wrong) that one queue of training images is created per GPU. Wouldn't the "right" way of doing things be to have a single queue feeding all of the towers? If so, is there an example available of a shared queue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're correct that the code for the CIFAR-10 model uses multiple input queues (through multiple calls to [`cifar10.distorted_inputs()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv_install) via `cifar10.tower_loss()`).

The easiest way to use a shared queue between the GPUs would be to do the following:

1. Increase the batch size by a factor of N, where N is the number of GPUs.
2. Move the call to `cifar10.distorted_inputs()` out of `cifar10.tower_loss()` and outside the [loop over GPUs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6936918ad8abd7ade445674d7c912e69157a1017/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L178).
3. Split the `images` and `labels` tensors that are returned from `cifar10.distorted_inputs()` along the 0th (batch) dimension:

   ```
   images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
   split_images = tf.split(0, FLAGS.num_gpus, images)
   split_labels = tf.split(0, FLAGS.num_gpus, labels)
   ```
4. Modify `cifar10.tower_loss()` to take `images` and `labels` arguments, and invoke it as follows:

   ```
   for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
     with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
       with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:

         loss = tower_loss(scope, split_images[i], split_labels[i])
   ```