# How to share a queue containing variable length sequences batches between multiple gpus?

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

According to [Tensorflow: Multi-GPU single input queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273951/tensorflow-multi-gpu-single-input-queue), it might be better to have a single queue shared by multiple GPUs.
And the link suggested that we could increase the batch size and then split batches by ourselves. However, when the input data are variable length sequences, increasing the batch size could result in many zero-padded values.

For example, If we create a 4-sequence batch and split the batch, it could be

`/gpu:0`

- `x, x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`
- `x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x`

---

`/gpu:1`

- `x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`
- `x, x, x, x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0`

My question is: How to produce batches like:

`/gpu:0`

- `x, x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`
- `x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x`

---

`/gpu:1`

- `x, x, 0, 0, 0`
- `x, x, x, x, x`

Following [slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py), I tried using a `tf.train.batch(data, batch_size=2, dynamic_pad=True)` to create batches, putting batches into a `tf.PaddingFIFOQueue`, and then calling `tf.PaddingFIFOQueue.dequeue()` on different GPUs. However, it seems that all GPUs got the same data on the latest tensorflow (master).

The following code demonstrate the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf

capacity = 10
queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity, tf.int64)
enqueue = queue.enqueue_many((list(range(capacity)),))

def clone_fn():
    clone_data = queue.dequeue()
    return clone_data

num_gpus = 2
all_clones_data = []
for gpu_index in range(num_gpus):
    with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(gpu_index)):
        all_clones_data.append(clone_fn())

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
    sess.run(enqueue)
    print(sess.run(all_clones_data))
```

On the latest tensorflow, the output is 
`[0, 0]`

On the older tensorflow (0.11), the output is
`[1, 0]`
, which is what I want.

It seems [slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py) also fetches the same data across all GPUs with the latest tensorflow.

Is there any better way to share a queue containing variable length sequences between multiple GPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running with

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))
```

This is a bit counter-intuitive:, filed [7038](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7038)