# prefetch_queue used in cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, prefetch

When I modify my tensorflow code into multi-gpu way, I find that each GPU receives the same batch data from `prefetch_queue`. It means models on GPUs receive the same data, and give the same loss value. The code about `prefetch_queue.dequeue` as follows:

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
      for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
          with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
            # Dequeues one batch for the GPU
            image_batch, label_batch = batch_queue.dequeue()
```

Comment: How is your `batch_queue` object define? Is it define on a particular device?

Comment: @Nicolas I define it out of the cycle scope.Like this:`batch_queue = tf.contrib.slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
                          [order, driver, feature, label], capacity=2 * FLAGS.num_gpus)`

Comment: Could you try using this argument `shared_name: (optional). If set, this queue will be shared under the given
      name across multiple sessions.` for the `prefetch_queue` method?

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks, I finally modify my code according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273951/tensorflow-multi-gpu-single-input-queue. Now the bottleneck is the data loading speed for queues.